# Make a WP7 Control work for WP8

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I implemented this control   http://www.sharpgis.net/post/2011/04/03/RefreshBox-for-Windows-Phone-7.aspx

which is a "Pull To Refresh". The code works perfectly for Windows Phone 7 and 7.1 (after setting  ScrollViewer.ManipulationMode ="Control" )

But when I want  updated the project to Windows Phone 8 the refresh event was not responsive anymore although the little animation to represent the "pull to refresh" is still working

Do I have to add anything to make it work on WP8 ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20541869/pull-to-refresh-on-windows-phone/20542854#20542854

Comment: It is not the same control i would like to use the code posted above for Windows phone 8.

Comment: The example you list is old and doesn't work properly under WP8. The answer referenced by @Xyroid works properly in WP8, please use it.