# Create DelegateCommand on ListBox

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, windows-phone

I would like to create a new Listbox or Longlistselector that implements this Pull To Refresh  here :

[Pull to refresh On Windows Phone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20541869/pull-to-refresh-on-windows-phone)

But instead of writing the "Pull To Refresh" on the code behind is it possible to create a command that I will call in the xaml ?

Like that :

```
<local:CustomLongListSelector   x:name = "List"   PullToRefresh = "{Binding SomeCommand}"/>
```

How can I eit my LongListSelector to add this command?