# Specific UI for refreshing items in the listbox windows phone

Tags: windows-phone-8, listbox, pull-to-refresh

I am familiar with the "pull to refresh" implementation for most of the android apps which implement lists.

I'm wondering if there is any specific UI for refreshing a list for windows mobile apps other than "pull to refresh".

Please suggest.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many Windows Phone apps now implement pull-to-refresh in lists. The RadDataBoundListBox from Telerik supports it, or you can use some of the [implementations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20541869/pull-to-refresh-on-windows-phone) available for standard ListBox.

Comment: Thank you. I think I've to go with "pull to refresh".