# How to detect end of scroll listbox?

Tags: windows-phone

I am trying to implement a pull to refresh on my windows phone application and using ListBox control,

I tried this sample : [Pull to refresh On Windows Phone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20541869/pull-to-refresh-on-windows-phone)  but it is not support for ListBox.I'm using Listbox and want to dectect end of scroll in listbox.(not LongListSelector) and so how do dectect end of scroll down in listbox control.

Note : I'm using listbox control because I want display item in Horizontal so I'm not use LongListSelector.

Answer (score 0):

you can detect Flick Gestures like top to bottom through VerticalVelocity of Flick events.

Comment: Thanks u,It's great,but I don't know how to detect end of scroll in Flick Gestures?

Comment: you can compute it by VerticalVelocity value.This value is changed as per your swipe size.

Comment: But the value is not erratic even if I'm swipe at the same location screen so I can not compute?

Comment: have you tried on actual device?emulator dont have swipe it uses mouse positions

Comment: Yes,I'm try on actual device,value is alway change.

Comment: but it will be in specific range if swipe area is same every time