# Update LongListSelector inside Panorama?

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8, longlistselector, panorama-control

I have a `LongListSelector` inside a `Panorama`.  I need a way to refresh the items in the `LongListSelector`.  It doesn't appear that I can make the `LongListSelector.ListHeader` into something touchable.  If that's possible, I can trigger a refresh if the header is touched.

Alternatively, I also can't figure out how to add a refresh button in the `Panorama` above the `LongListSelector`.  The XAML won't compile if I include other controls in the `PanoramaItem` with the `LongListSelector`.

Any guidance?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using pull to refresh feature.

I found this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20541869/pull-to-refresh-on-windows-phone)

Hope it helps