# What the event for the scrollviewer scroll to top and continue scroll in windows phone?

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1

At the desktop application when we scroll a list to the top, normally we are not able to scroll any more. But in the phone, we drag the list to the top and continue to drag, some white space will be show. Like the example below.

When user scroll the list normal, I could subscribe the ViewChanged event to know the list is been scrolling. But after the list is scroll to the top and continue to scroll, the scrollviewer's vertical offset is already be 0 and will not changed, and the ViewChanged event will not be fired.

My question is is there any way to know a list is been dragged to top and continued dragged?

My target platform is windows phone 8.1 and my sample code:

```
<Grid>
    <Frame >
        <Grid>
            <ScrollViewer x:Name="TopViewer">
                <StackPanel >
                    <Grid Background="Blue" Height="10"/>
                    <local:CustomListView x:Name="List" 
                                          Background="LightBlue">
                        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBlock FontSize="15" Foreground="Black" Text="{Binding}"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    </local:CustomListView>
                </StackPanel>
            </ScrollViewer>
        </Grid>
    </Frame>
</Grid>
```

xaml.cs

```
        List<string> l = new List<string>();
        Random r = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++)
        {
            l.Add(r.Next().ToString());
        }
        List.ItemsSource = l;
```

[image]

Comment: To make sure I understand your question. When you scroll to the top, you are able to scroll even further? What happens when you take off the finger of the touch screen then? Does the list stay or is it adjusting itself so that the first item is on top again? (so there is no gap left)

Comment: @Stephan after the list scroll to the top, I could scroll for a little further, when I take off the finger, the list will go back on the top again.

Comment: OK, then this is works as designed by Windows Phone (and also Windows 8). It is a design element by the UI so that users understand that you are actually on top and there is nothing more to see. So this is actually implemented into the framework and you won't be able change that. This is no issue with your code.

Answer (score 0):

This is works as designed by Windows Phone (and also Windows 8). It is a design element by the UI so that users understand that you are actually on top and there is nothing more to see. So this is actually implemented into the framework and you won't be able change that. This is no issue with your code.

Comment: I don't want to change it, I just need to know when the list is dragged to the top.

Comment: Ah, I understand now. You are basically searching for an event that gets fired due to "pull-to-refresh" action on the list, right? ListView doesn't provide this. I only of some commercial controls like Telerik's WP controls with the DataBoundList control that provide this functionality. Maybe this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20541869/pull-to-refresh-on-windows-phone) helps, too but it is just for Windows Phone 8.0 (therefore Silverlight). Not sure if it works for Universal also.

Comment: thx for your reply. Yes, I want to know the event due to "pull-to-refresh", but I need do some other action other than refresh. I checked the link you given, it base on the LongListSelector control, which has been removed in WP 8.1. And the Telerik WP control is also target to the WP 8.0.

Comment: I am not sure about universal apps but there was a ScrollStates VisualStateGroup in WP8 for scrollviewer to achieve your goal. More info: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/slmperf/archive/2011/06/30/windows-phone-mango-change-listbox-how-to-detect-compression-end-of-scroll-states.aspx Maybe there is some replacement, take a look at universal scrollviewer default style.

Comment: Searching for some other functionality I stumpled across Krempel's WP7 Library. According to [link](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Krempel.WP7) it provides support for a pull-to-refresh panel. I didn't test it but your question immediately came to my mind when I read this. Maybe you wanna give it a try.